# loopin in .load in jquery

Tags: jquery

why load() function loops almost 23 times when i have only eight elements with .image class

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var i=0;

    $('.image').load(function(){
    console.log(i++);
    });
});
```

my html is

```
<div class="pel homepics">
    <div class="left i1" ><a href="#" ><img class="image" src="image1.png"/></a></div>
    <div class="left i1" ><a href="#" ><img class="image" src="image1.png"/></a></div>
    <div class="left i1" ><a href="#" ><img class="image" src="image1.png"/></a></div>
    <div class="left i1" ><a href="#" ><img class="image" src="image1.png"/></a></div>
    <div class="left i1" ><a href="#" ><img class="image" src="image1.png"/></a></div>
    <div class="left i1" ><a href="#" ><img class="image" src="image1.png"/></a></div>
    <div class="left i1" ><a href="#" ><img class="image" src="image1.png"/></a></div>
    <div class="left i1" ><a href="#" ><img class="image" src="image1.png"/></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: looped 8 times for me. http://jsfiddle.net/Cecv7/1/

Comment: here too, are you sure there are no other `.images`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.each($('.image'),function(i,ele){
        $(ele).load(function(){
            alert(ele.attr("title")+" loaded");
        });    
    });    
});
```